# Saving dynamic values into database

Tags: php, arrays, database, loops, foreach

First my code is below

```
$address_value_array = array($_POST['rta_pic_pc'], $_POST['rta_pic_house']);
foreach ($address_value_array as $value) {

    Test::save(array(null, $value, null, $value));
}
```

In my system user can have more than one address to one of my clients profile, therefore when saving I'll have to check if user have entered one two or more than two address in how should i use foreach loop on that occasion to enter value into database.

I've tried with $key value set as well but get errors.

```
$address_value_array = array($_POST['rta_pic_pc'], $_POST['rta_pic_house']);
foreach ($address_value_array as $key => $value) {

    Test::save(array(null, $value[$key], null, $value[$key]));
}
```

If you can help me how to insert that values into database

**btw rta_pic_pc = Postcode, rta_pic_house = house no**

Kind Regards

[image]

Comment: Your array `$address_value_array` doesn't have a key, it's just an indexed array. Is `$_POST['rta_pic_pc']` supposed to be a key for `$_POST['rta_pic_house']` ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the POST variables. Is the user able to POST more than one address when they submit the form?? If not then I can't see a need for an array. Just take the address variables submitted and save them using your Class...

Comment: off course i'm on edit screen there they have all of their previous address and and they can add new too dont worry about adding more than one if it is possible or not.. it is that why i've posted this post... regards

Comment: What parameters takes save() function?

Comment: rta_pic_pc and rta_pic_house are parts of one address, is that right? And you wan to check if there is more than one address entered? Shouldn't $address_value_array than be two-dimensional?

Comment: There is a minimum one address but could be two or three.. let me try two dimensional array

Comment: Are you saying they could submit in **ONE** form submission multiple addresses? Or do they simply submit one address at a time?

Comment: what is happening here is it is edit screen they already have enterd one address screen now here they can add more or edit previous which could be 5 could be one million but more than one address

Comment: So if understand there "could" be multiple Postcode boxes on your page for example. And the user can edit any or all of them. Does each Postcode box have the same name of `rta_pic_pc`. If so that won't work. Each form field has to have a unique name.

Comment: lemme put screen shot

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot. There are three `POSTCODE` boxes in that screen shot, do they each have different names. If they are all called `rta_pic_pc` then what you want to do is not possible. At the top of the PHP page can you do `print_r($_POST)` it will show all the variables that were posted from the form.

Comment: no it is declared like `name='rta_pic_pc[]'` for those which are already save and `name='rta_pic_pc_new'` for the add new address

Comment: Brilliant. Then a dump of $_POST array should show you exactly how to get the elements out. You can post the dump here if you like and I can have a go at it... `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: @superphonic you can try what would like to me dump?

Comment: Thank you @superphonic i've got it working i can post the answer here if you're interested?

Comment: Sure, It may be useful to others that come across this question.

Comment: @superphonic it is done you can view it now

Answer (score 1):

I think that like this you put also the $key, but I am not sure:

```
$address_value_array = [];
array_push ( $address_value_array , $_POST['rta_pic_pc'], $_POST['rta_pic_house'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments and me not really knowing what your save function is expecting, how about:

```
Test::save(array(null, $_POST['rta_pic_pc'], null, $_POST['rta_pic_house']));
```

Comment: No, you don't seem to need a `foreach` loop. From what I can tell, a user submits an address, and then you just need to save this address.

Comment: there is three address already save and now i'm editing screen this will not work

Comment: The already saved addresses don't matter do they? they are already saved. The user is only submitting another single address isn't he? He is not submitting in one go multiple addresses is he?

Comment: lemme post a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Hello folks I've found solution to my answer

What i did since i had a hidden variable that stores the id of already saved addresses i used that to loop and then catch the value inside the loop if that is not making sense let me put the code down here

HTML:

```
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    while ($person_address = $person_addresses->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $address_row = Address::findByID($person_address->address_id);

?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group" id="div_pic_pc<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            <label class="control-label">Postcode<span class="required" aria-required="true" > * </span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="rta_pic_person_add_id[]" value="<?php echo $address_row->id; ?>" />
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $address_row->postcode; ?>" name="rta_pic_pc<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="rta_pic_pc<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group" id="div_pic_house<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            <label class="control-label">House Number<span class="required" aria-required="true" > * </span></label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $address_row->house_no; ?>" name="rta_pic_house<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="rta_pic_house<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group" id="div_pic_flat<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            <label class="control-label">Flat Number</label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $address_row->flat_no; ?>" name="rta_pic_flat<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="rta_pic_flat<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group" id="div_pic_street<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            <label class="control-label">Street</label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $address_row->street; ?>" name="rta_pic_street<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="rta_pic_street<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group" id="div_pic_town<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            <label class="control-label">Town</label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $address_row->town; ?>" name="rta_pic_town<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="rta_pic_town<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group" id="div_pic_county<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            <label class="control-label">County</label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $address_row->county; ?>" name="rta_pic_county<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="rta_pic_county<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
        $counter++;
    endwhile; 
?>
```

PHP:

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($_POST['rta_pic_person_add_id'] as $value) {

    $postcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rta_pic_pc' . $counter]);
    $houseno = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rta_pic_house' . $counter]);
    $flatno = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rta_pic_flat' . $counter]);
    $street = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rta_pic_street' . $counter]);
    $town = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rta_pic_town' . $counter]);
    $county = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rta_pic_county' . $counter]);

    Address::save(array($value, $flatno, $houseno, $street, $town, $postcode, $county));

    $counter++;
}
```